# The right to hide one's password

Tags: european-union, data-protection, security

It's well known that [you should never reveal your password to anyone](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/is-it-ok-to-tell-your-password-to-your-companys-sysadmin) -- including your boss, your sysadmin, etc. My friend's former boss has sued her, demanding (among other things) the password to her account on the company's Mac laptop she used for work. (They have the laptop but claim they cannot use it w/out the password.)

I am asking for an *authoritive reference* to a regulation, law, best practice or whatever for a case like this, where "authoritive" means something more authoritive for a judge than a SE answer -- e.g. a law, a textbook, an Apple manual, a sysadmin rulebook or something along the lines. Ideally, the reference should also state the prescribed practice as "absolutely universal" (or maybe even better) Mac- or EU-specific (the company is in EU).

A related question: are passwords covered by data protection regulations (e.g. GDPR)?

Comment: I doubt there is any such law. You can get a lot of opinions at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23388/do-i-have-to-relinquish-my-pc-password-to-my-former-boss, but there's no legal backing up of those opinions there. There are still country-specific laws in the EU, and there are country differences in the obligation to reveal encryption keys to law enforcement.

Comment: GDPR almost certainly wouldn't come into play here, because of the employer-employee relationship and the matter being related to company equipment.  Why is your friend against handing her password over?  They shouldn't be reusing passwords and if the presence of the password is preventing the company from retrieving valuable information (ie because the user accounts home directory is encrypted using the account password) then there may very well be a case to answer by your friend.

Comment: @Moo They claim they *cannot use the computer* w/out the password, which should be wrong even if the account is encrypted (which it probably isn't -- certainly not by her (there's nothing important on the computer)). All relevant info on the internet points to the conclusion that they do not need the password, i.e. they are just using it opportunistically for bolstering their case (and fooling the court in the process)

Comment: @jaam if they want access to the account, thats their right - the account and everything in it is company property - they or a court gets to make the judgement about whats important and what isnt, not the employee and they certainly don't have to trust the employees word on this matter.  Again, I ask the question why is your friend against handing her password over?

Comment: @Moo Since my friend is plotting a counter-case for the company, it would be useful to show that the company doesn't need the password to access the account (sysadmins should be able to override the password) and has deliberately fooled the court

Comment: @jaam if the account is encrypted, admins cant override that unless the device management system was in place beforehand.  And I dont get the point of you saying "deliberately fooled the court" - its both sides job to disprove the other sides case, the court is never "fooled" because the court shouldnt have inherent knowledge of what is and is not possible in complex situations - its up to the opposing sides to supply that information.

Comment: @Moo Thanks. She didn't encrypt anything, so either it was encrypted by default, is unencrypted or encrypted by sysadmins after they got the computer. I'm starting to think maybe Security StackExchange would be a better place for the question

Comment: If there is company property on the laptop, and the laptop is encrypted, then the company might be able to sue and have the court compel your friend to reveal the password.

Comment: Was she given the laptop for shared professional/private use? If private use was allowed, asking for a password would likely be improper. However, she could likely be asked to assist with extracting business data, or to factory-reset the device.

Comment: Is your friend working with a lawyer on this, and are you looking for this on the lawyer's advice?

Comment: It's a US case, and a fairly extreme example but courts held that Terry Childs had committed a felony by failing to reveal a password.

Comment: @NateEldredge She's working w/ a lawyer but asking on SE was my idea (I suppose I should try to get authoritive technical references from Security SE)

Comment: @richardb what about https://www.law.com/thelegalintelligencer/2019/11/25/pa-high-court-rules-that-fifth-amendment-protects-digital-passwords

Answer (score 2):

You have the right to keep your password secret. But if this causes damages, you can be held responsible for the damages.

Simple example: Your company provided iPhone, worth £1,000, is protected with your passcode. Without that passcode it is literally unusable. You refuse to provide the passcode. If you refuse to provide the passcode, AND refuse to reset the phone using your passcode, you can be held responsible for the damages.

Another example: Your computer, containing your work product that is owned by the company, is protected with your password. If you refuse to hand over the password AND refuse to change the password to 1234 for example, you can be held responsible for damages.

You don’t have to provide your password, but you have to prevent damages caused by this.

Comment: The main question probably is, what counts as an evidence that a damage has been caused. They said "they cannot use the computer and had to buy a new one". Does just saying this (plus, hypothetically, a plausibly dated bill for a new computer) suffice for an evidence of the damage caused, let's say, in the price of the new computer + 1000$ for whatever work they say they might have done w/ the old one in the meantime? (All the work results, as I understood, are in the cloud so it seems difficult to argue for results that should be only in the computer)

Answer (score 1):

The GDPR requires the processing entity to apply "Appropriate Technical and Organisational Measures" to ensure compliance. Article 32 says

> Taking into account the state of the art, the costs of implementation and the nature, scope, context and purposes of processing as well as the risk of varying likelihood and severity for the rights and freedoms of natural persons, the controller and the processor shall implement appropriate technical and organisational measures to ensure a level of security appropriate to the risk, [...]

Article 40 (2) says

> Associations and other bodies representing categories of controllers or processors may prepare codes of conduct, or amend or extend such codes, for the purpose of specifying the application of this Regulation
> [...]
> (h) the measures and procedures referred to in Articles 24 and 25 and the measures to ensure security of processing referred to in Article 32;

These articles do **not** spell out directly that revealing passwords is against proper TOM, but in my judgement revealing a personalized password is not in accordance with the state of the art. When there is a technical requirement to share secrets between several individuals, they should be kept in a secure system where each user has an individual, non-shared access that can be logged.

But involving the GDPR that was might not be the most reasonable or constructive solution to the problem. This isn't really a question for Law SE, it is one for The Workplace SE or Information Security SE.

If the laptop contains only business/professional data, help them to recover that data. Meet in a cafe or somewhere like that. Log in. Copy all data files onto a stick. If your friend is the only one with an admin account, have her create *another* admin user for the company.

If the situation is tense, bring a witness and have the company sign a protocol of what was done and precisely when. This *should* have been done during out-processing.

Comment: You aren't addressing the legal question of legal basis for compelling a person to provide a password. OP confused the matter by irrelevantly asking about "best practices" and "Apple mnuals", which aren't legally enforceable.

Comment: @user6726, the GDPR Art. 32 says "Taking into account the state of the art, the costs of implementation and the nature, scope, context and purposes of processing as well as the risk of varying likelihood and severity for the rights and freedoms of natural persons, the controller and the processor shall implement appropriate technical and organisational measures to ensure a level of security appropriate to the risk, [...]" This could be considered a legal reason for **not** compelling the surrender of a password, since that is clearly not the *state of the art* in security policies.

Comment: Doe that mean you plan on editing your answer to be law-based?

Comment: @user6726, I edited it, but I don't think that makes my answer more helpful ...

Comment: Who are controller and processor? "If your friend is the only one with an admin account..." -- She's a regular user, not an admin. Since an admin created her account, the company's claim that they cannot use the laptop is probably false

Comment: @jaam, re admin account, depends on the size of the company and their professionalism. A small company might tell an employee to create accounts on factory-fresh computer. Re controller, if there is any customer **or** employee data on the machine, the company would be the controller/processor and required to apply TOM. An order to hand over passwords may be unprofessional and hence not "good TOM." But I explained in the second part of my answer that going the GDPR route is not helpful.

Comment: @jaam the company's claim that they cannot use the computer without the password might be *mistaken* rather than *deceptive.*  In other words, they might actually believe that they cannot use the computer without the password, in which case they're not lying, they're just incompetent (or, more charitably, ignorant).  I used to work for someone who required us to give all our passwords because of similar ignorance.

Comment: @phoog no it's not mistaken (it has been repeateadly said to them to ask from their sysadmins, to which there've been zero response). so it's either deceptive *or* a procedural fault (e.g. sysadmin(s) forgot their password(s) or what ever). At this point, giving them a password or even just logging into the computer and then giving it back to them carries a substantial risk of being framed w/ false evidence